# I am getting SHA256 checksum mismatch error with brew install "formula"

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am using MAC OS and for the first time I am trying to create my own package using brew package manager.
I have placed a simple helloworld shell script inside a tar file and pushed it to my github repository.
Please refer to the link https://github.com/shahritesh16/tutorial1.
I have written simple formula which is shown below:

```
class Script < Formula
  desc "Shell script for hello world"
  homepage "https://github.com/shahritesh16/tutorial1"
  url "https://github.com/shahritesh16/tutorial1/blob/master/brewtest-0.1.tar.gz"
  sha256 "30f1cc5cabe3b988d567e561713eae01840c4c0781daf7e2709c9c6b79dba4b1"
  def install
        echo Welcome
  end
end
```

I have created the tar.gz file using these commands:
`tar -cvf brewtest-0.1.tar.gz brewdir`
I have calculated the sha256 value using `shasum -a 256 /location/brewtest-0.1.tar.gz` and added the value in ruby script `script.rb`.
Up on executing the command, brew install script.rb I am getting ChecksumMismactherror.
Below is the output:

```
==> Downloading https://github.com/shahritesh16/tutorial1/blob/master/brewtest-0.1.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%  
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:  
ChecksumMismatchError: SHA256 mismatch  
Expected: 30f1cc5cabe3b988d567e561713eae01840c4c0781daf7e2709c9c6b79dba4b1  
  Actual: 39524ab2e5177ddbb9d9cfac7c535ea5c6f290e8ecbbec6b67de189ba5435c6e  
 Archive: /Users/xyzUser/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/e0b1da9a7a7fff80ece6531f3f5660d6a8bf4e1fba006910543da58e44330f5d--brewtest-0.1.tar.gz  
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error as I am using correct SHA256 value in script.rb as per `shasum -a 256 filelocation` command.  Also Why it is comparing sha256 value from script.rb with the one that is downloaded in /Users/xyzUser/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads.

Comment: FYI `-cvf` is not sufficient to create a `.tar.gz`. Your archive is a tar file, it’s not gzipped. You should use `-czvf` instead. I’ve a [blog post](https://bfontaine.net/blog/2016/09/17/do-you-speak-tar/) that explains that if you’re interested.

Answer (score 1):

The checksum mismatches is due to an error in the URL. `https://github.com/shahritesh16/tutorial1/blob/master/brewtest-0.1.tar.gz` points to the HTML-rendered version of the file. What you should have used is the URL you get when clicking on the "Raw" button on this file:

```
https://github.com/shahritesh16/tutorial1/raw/master/brewtest-0.1.tar.gz
```

Note the "`raw`" part in that URL.

Also, the formula’s name should match its filename: use `Brewtest` instead of `Script`:

```
class Brewtest < Formula
  desc "Shell script for hello world"
  homepage "https://github.com/shahritesh16/tutorial1"
  url "https://github.com/shahritesh16/tutorial1/raw/master/brewtest-0.1.tar.gz"
  sha256 "30f1cc5cabe3b988d567e561713eae01840c4c0781daf7e2709c9c6b79dba4b1"

  def install
    puts "Hello"
  end
end
```

Comment: I could not understand your comment about the role of "raw" in the URL.  I am getting the exact URL which I mentioned in the desc.What will be the "raw" part in my URL?

Comment: The "raw" URL points to the raw file, while the non-"raw" one points to GitHub’s HTML. Try making a `curl` on both URLs to see the difference (or open them in your browser).